# Asking for file name

Tags: c++, input

Sample

Please give the filename: out
Error opening file. Please try again. Please give the filename: in
Error opening file. Please try again. Please give the filename: inpou                              Error opening file. Please try again. 
Please make sure that the file you are trying to open exists.

Please give the filename: input.txt

```
void name()

{
    char fname [40];
    done=false;

    do {
        cout<< "Please give the filename: ";
        cin.getline(fname, sizeof(fname));
        infile.open(fname);
            if (infile.fail()){
                cout<< "Error opening file. Please try again.";
                infile.clear();

            }
            else done= true;
            cout<<endl;
            }
    while(!done);


}
```

I need to tell the user "Please make sure that the file you are trying to open exists. 
" after every third failed attempt.  Any suggestions I'm not sure how to make it work.

Comment: Have a counter and an `if` statement inside `if (infile.fail()){}` block perhaps?

Comment: 1. The style of the code is like your business card, messy code makes a bad impression. Please fix this. 2. Make a complete example which compiles. 3. Don't use `using namespace std;` in your code, this is considered bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include a counter that you increment upon each invalid file open attempt. Once you check if the value stored in the counter is the third attempt, you can emit the message.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an example implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

std::string name()
{
    for (int tryCount = 0;; ++tryCount) {
        char fileName[1024];
        std::cout << "Please give the filename: ";
        std::cin.getline(fileName, sizeof(fileName));
        std::ifstream infile(fileName);
        if (infile.fail()) {
            std::cout << "Error opening file. Please try again." << std::endl;
            if (tryCount % 3 == 2) {
                std::cout << "Please make sure the filename is correct." << std::endl;
            }
            infile.clear();
        } else {
            return std::string(fileName);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << name();
}
```